# (WKSP_LOGENOUM.FK_WRITTENBY1) violated - parent key not found

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39mF1.png)
(WKSP_LOGENOUM.FK_WRITTENBY1) violated - parent key not found

how to insert the data(new) other than already in to table ?

i want can enter the data into form other than in parents table
what function need to be add on here
i am new here(developer)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you have entered the data into the parent table before you enter it into the child table (which has a referential constraint to the parent table).